# folium map with simple slider as stand alone html

Tags: python, folium, folium-plugins

I've got this basic folium map

```
import folium
from folium import plugins

m = folium.Map(
    location=[51.5, -0.09],
    zoom_start=11
)
m.save('map.html')
```

I want to add a slider on the bottom that changes the colour of the pins based on the time. i've got a txt file that has the name of the place, the longitude, latitude, and variable and value. I'm not sure how to make a slider with the variable numbers that would then correspond to the value [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1] that would correspond to a change in colour of the pin on the map.

```
names   longitude   latitude    variable    value
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    1   1
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    2   1
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    3   1
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    4   1
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    5   0.5
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    6   0.75
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    7   0.25
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    8   0.25
Bank of friendship  -0.0990573382928028 51.5583162622095    9   0
```

hoping you can help!